# Doobie transact over a list of ConnectionIO programs

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie

Let's say I have a list of Doobie programs (all with `Unit` type parameters, fwiw):

```
val progList: List[ConnectionIO[Unit]] = prog1 :: prog2 :: ... :: Nil
```

Is there any way I can run them in one transaction? A for-comprehension won't work here, because I only know the precise composition of the program list at runtime. Essentially, I suppose I need to fold them together, I guess.

I suppose this question applies to Free Monads in Cats in general, so I'll tag Cats as well. Thanks.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Isn't that ticket about the reverse operation?

Comment: You're right, read it backwards :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that with `.sequence` from cats:

```
import doobie.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

...

val res = progList.sequence // ConnectionIO[List[Unit]]
```